# Is it possible to perform a real-time audio noise reduction in android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, noise-reduction

I am using real-time ASR(Automatic Speech Recognition) service for andoird and iOS development. I find that if there is background noise when I am speaking, the effect of ASR is not good.

I think performing a audio noise reduction could solve this problem, and I have to perform it before sending real-time audio data to the ASR service.

How can I perform a real-time audio noise reduction in android and iOS?
If it is impossible, is there an another way to solve my problem?

I have tried to look for a plugin or package and etc. but none was found.

Comment: On iOS, you can use voice processing. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioionode/3152100-setvoiceprocessingenabled